# I want to write a function in python which returns true if all the digits are even

Tags: python, for-loop

The function is all_even in which you input an int and it returns bool. It returns true if all the digits are even. e.g. all_even(2224) gives true and all_even(1362) gives false.

I wrote the code but it is not working properly.

This is what I have:

```
def is_very_even(num: int) -> bool: 
    even = False
    strnum = str(num)
    for ch in strnum:
       if int(ch)% 2==0:
          even = True
    return even
```

The code gives true even if the num has a single even num and the rest are odd e.g all_even(231) is true which is supposed to be false. Can somebody tell me what is wrong with it.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a recursive approach (without converting to a string):

```
def allEven(N): return True if N==0 else N%2==0 and allEven(N//10)
```

output:

```
allEven(246) # True   
allEven(123) # False
```

*Note that the issue with your function is that you set `even` to `True` as soon as you encounter an even digit.  If there is an odd digit after that, your `even` variable remains `True`.  This will tell you that "at least one" digit is even, not that they are all even.*

Answer (score 2):

You are checking if all the numbers are even. So first assume that it's true, all the numbers are even and set `even = True`. Then check if there is any odd number in the string. If there is, then set `even = False`

Now, if there is any odd number in the string, `even` will be `False` and therefore we can verify it.

```
def is_very_even(num: int) -> bool: 
    even = True
    
    strnum = str(num)
    for ch in strnum:
       if int(ch)% 2 !=0:
          even = False
          
    return even
```

This code can also be improvised like this. We don't need to keep checking if we found a single odd number. We can just return false immediately. And if all the numbers checks out but none returns false, then it must be an all even string.

```
def is_very_even(num: int) -> bool: 
    for ch in str(num):
       if int(ch)% 2 !=0:
          return False
          
    return True
```

Answer (score 1):

I would solve it like this:

```
def is_very_even(s) -> bool:
    return all(int(x) % 2 == 0 for x in str(s))
```

This converts every character to an integer and checks if it is even with modulo. This is processed in a so called `generator expression`.

Then we use the builtin `all` method to check if the generator delivers only `True` values.

Comment: I think you need to change "s" into "num", right?

Comment: and even then I get the following error with Python 3.8: 
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: Thank you for your hints. I was not checking my solution properly. I think now it will solve your problem :)